# Передача переменных PHP из одного PHP-файла в другой с помощью ajax

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте!

Необходимо передать две переменные без перезагрузки страницы при клике на элемент. На данный момент код имеет такой вид:

```
var id = "<?php echo $row["id"];?>";
var count_vk = "1";
var count_fb = "1";
var count_tw = "1";

$(document).ready( function() {

$("#share_wrap_vk").click(function(){
$.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: '/blocks/share_counter.php',
data: ""

});
});

$("#share_wrap_fb").click(function(){
$.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: '/blocks/share_counter.php',
data: ""

});
});

$("#share_wrap_tw").click(function(){
$.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: '/blocks/share_counter.php',
data: ""

});
});

});
```

Нужно передать id и count_vk документу share_counter.php. count_vk, fb, tw необходимы только для того, чтобы понять, какое поле обновить в таблице базы данных. id получаю при загрузке страницы из бд. Суть скрипта - считать количество кликов на ссылку с конкретным идентификатором.

Comment: @Torawhite, унифицировать языки - идея плохая.  
Разнообразие видов - единственное, что спасает нас от вымирания, плюс - это весело, всё разное :)  
Даже если бы пришлось объединить языки, то лучше в JS, когда с ним познакомишься лучше, ты поймёшь что он куда лучше PHP (хотя сравнивать их - это как сравнивать морковку и самолёт).

Comment: @Torawhite, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В ajax запросе в поле data передавай объект.

**Обновление**

```
var id = "<?php echo $row["id"];?>";
var count_vk = "1";
var count_fb = "1";
var count_tw = "1";

var wrapAjax = function(soc){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/blocks/share_counter.php',
    data: {
      count: soc
    }
  }); 
};

$(document).ready( function() {
  var $document = $(document);
  $document.on('click',"#share_wrap_vk",wrapAjax(count_vk));
  $document.on('click',"#share_wrap_fb",wrapAjax(count_fb));
  $document.on('click',"#share_wrap_tw",wrapAjax(count_tw));
});
```

Comment: а вообще можно было бы и лучше написать код

Comment: Это ясно, мне не совсем понятен синтаксис. То бишь, я же не могу просто переписать переменные, которые мне нужно передать через запятую. Ещё не ясно, сработает ли такой вид var id = "<?php echo $row["id"];?>"; То есть попадёт ли нужное значение и сама переменная в функцию ниже?

Comment: @Torawhite, если `$row['id']` - это цифра, то кавычки не нужны:  
`var id = <? print $row['id']; ?>;`
На будущее - разделяй модель и вид, одно в другом писать плохо, сам же запутаешься.

Answer (score 0):

Быдлокод это, а концепция как-то так:

```
// File: Some.js
$(function(){
 $('#your_button').on('click', function(){
  $.post('target.php', {
   id: 'your_variable_with_id_here'
  });
 });
});

<? // File: target.php
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Это да, но я сомневаюсь, что в начале карьеры нужно связывать FrontEnd, ИМХО.

Comment: @TheDoctor я никакую карьеру программиста не делаю, делаю только сайт для себя, вот и всё.

Comment: Я же написал, что на место "`'your_variable_with_id_here'`" нужно поставить твой ID из JS, если он в переменной `id`, то так: `id: id` :)

Comment: @TheDoctor  То есть id: id, count_vk: 1?
Иначе обработчик не поймёт, какому поле нужно обновить (vk, fb, tw)Не сомневаюсь, что можно сделать более грамотно, но я не знаю как. В обработчик приходит массив с двумя переменными id и одна из переменных count. В нём код если существует $_POST['count_vk'], то обновляй одну ячейку, если существует $_POST['count_fb'] то обновляй вторую ячейку и также с tw

Comment: Это можно решить как-то так:

    <?
    $id = $_POST['id']; // Получаем ID из пришедшего массива
    if($_POST['count_vk'])
     // Обновляем поля контакта
    if($_POST['count_fb'])
     // Обновляем поля ФБР, т.е. фейсбука
    if($_POST['count_tw'])
     // Обновляем поля твикстера
    // Etc...

Comment: С обработчиком-то мне всё более менее понятно? с php давно сталкиваюсь. Главное, чтобы при клике в обработчик попал массив с двумя переменными. Если я Вас правильно понял, то это будет корректный вариант кода:
var id = "<?php echo $row["id"];?>";
var count_vk = "1";
var count_fb = "1";
var count_tw = "1";

$(function(){
$('#share_wrap_vk').on('click', function(){
$.post('/blocks/share_counter.php', {
id: 'id: id, count_vk: 1'
});
});
});
И такой же код для двух следующих кнопок?

Comment: В кнопке, например, твиттера, нужно отправлять это:  
`{
 id: id,
 type: 'twitter'
}`

В кнопке фейсбука это:
`{
 id: id,
 type: 'facebook'
}`

И так далее.  
Тогда в пыхе можно написать что-то типа:  
`<?
$id = $_POST['id'];
switch($_POST['type']){
 case 'twitter':
  // Обновляем твиттер
 case 'facebook':
  // Обновляем фейсбук
}`
Добавляя больше кейсов делаешь обработку остальных.

Comment: @TheDoctor про switch впервые узнал, можно и так. Спасибо! Главное, чтобы переменные пришли, обработать в php - это для меня уже не так сложно, как js с совершенно иным синтаксисом и алгоритмом. Неужели нельзя как-то унифицировать синтаксис языков, которые используются в разработке сайтов - запутаться легко, освоить сложно. (